# Using postman for login testing

Tags: php

I am trying to login page with `postman`.

The system is made by `laravel`

My top page is like this below ,so it makes the _token automatically , and
login by submitting `email` and `password` to http://localhost/login

```
   <div class="card" style="border: 1px solid #ced4da; border-radius: 0;">
        <div class="card-body login-card-body">

            <form action="http://localhost/login" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="APiqx3F5lxfBKvgPhV3uzzrj824afqLohGS1Lwx6">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control " value="" placeholder="email" autofocus>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control " placeholder="パスワード">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                        </div>
                <div class="row">
               
         
               
                    
                    <div class="col-12"; style="text-align:right;">

                      <button type="submit" class="btn" style="margin: 0 auto;background-color: #007bff;color:white; width: 100%;">
                        login 
                     
                      </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried like this but it says the POST method is not supported.

[image]

What is the correct way to test the login ??

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong route. The route you should be using is localhost/login as this is the POST one.

Comment: It's good that you want to answer and you should keep it up! However, in situations like this, we tend to leave a comment about what's wrong and then vote to close it as a typo-question instead of answering them. It's very unlikely this question will be of any use for future visitors.

Comment: Oh makes more sense that way. Seems like the route being called is a GET one. Thanks for teaching

Comment: Yes that's right I should use /login thank you for your ocmment.

Comment: If you found your answer you can close the question by accepting an answer or uploading your own.

Answer (score -1):

First thing to fix is `http://localhost/login` is the url. You need to add `/login` endpoint to the url. Next thing is, the particular url is defined in `GET` method. It is better to change it to `POST` method in your code.

Comment: THank you for you comment,yes I should add `login`